# get the class type in a self referencing, generic class, static constructor

Tags: c#, generics

ok, this is not an easy question, and code would help me explain the problem.

what i need is a way to get the class type in a self referencing, generic class, static constructor

Imagine you have code like this:

```
public class ClassA : BaseClass<ClassA>{
}
public abstract class BaseClass<T> where T : BaseClass<T> {
    static readonly int _aValue;
    static BaseClass(){
       //here i have code that load _avalue for each kind of T type, based on my own logic
       _aValue=1;

       //need to get the real type here
    }
    public int GetValue() {
       return _aValue;
    }
}


ClassA c = new ClassA();
Console.WriteLine(c.GetValue());
```

then when you do something like

```
ClassA c = new ClassA();
Console.WriteLine(c.GetValue());
```

here what happen is that the static constructor get invoked and it load in my example the value to the static variable

I need to know in the static constructor, if the type that's invoking the constructor (in generic type constructor each derived class invoke it, so i assume i can do what i need) if the T type is actually ClassA

my real need is to know if I declared correctly my class definition because i haven't find a nice way to ensure that a self referencing type is real self referenced, because in my tests i found that

```
ClassX : Message<ClassAAA>
```

doesn't rise an error while i want to enforce

```
ClassA : Message<ClassA>
ClassB : Message<ClassB>
ClassC : Message<ClassC>
```

and not

```
ClassD : Message<DifferentClass>
```

any clue?

I already tried using MethodInfo.GetMethod().DeclaringType but it returns the base class

**UPDATE**
ok let me try to explain a bit more
In my scenario, I use this kind of design to have custom messages definition that i use in my client/server scenario and each different message derived class must have a byte that specify the "message id", so i use attributes to decorate my classes and that attribute allow me to specify an enum value (so i don't have magic numbers around the code)

In my static constructor of Message base class, i use reflection to read the attribute value and store it into its static _aValue member, so every kind of Message have its own message id, and it's loaded only once every message type, and not during instance constructor, for performance reasons.
It works very well, I can have let say a class like

```
[MyAttribute(MyMessages.Ping)]
public class PingMessage : Message<PingMessage>
```

and whenever my PingMessage class is istantiated, i can get its static messageTye value and i'm happy with that, the problem is that sometimes happen that because of a mistake, i create a class like

```
[MyAttribute(MyMessages.Ping)]
public class PingMessage : Message<AnotherMessage>
```

and the generic constraints doesn't rise a compile time error because AnotherMessage is another class that inherit from Message so it's legit, but i want to enforce that if you inherit from Message, the T must be the class that's inherithing, so just allow

```
PingMessage : Message<PingMessage>
```

i know that there aren't generic constraints that allow me to do this, and i can't of course add derived class in the constrains, because i don't know which messages i'll create (and anyway having lots of message it doesn't make sense) so i wanted to do my type constrains checks during the static constructor of the message type, because I'm already doing something there and so it seemed to me the best place to put my checks, rising exceptions if the types aren't wrong or no attribute specified on the class

I technically could do this kind of checks in my instances constructor, but performance is important so i can't.

I thought about having my Message implement a custom interface and then having a method of that interface that checks the types, and invoke that only during initialization, but i was looking for an easier approach if possible, but it seems reflection can't help me here

Comment: `if (c is ClassA)`? [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) -- the example appears to match the pattern you're looking for.

Comment: You cannot know that in static constructor because it's well static and is not "invoked" by any type. What if you do this in instance constructor and throw exception if class is not self-referencing?

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do it in the static constructor and not the instance constructor?

Comment: Please note that the static constructor of `BaseClass<X>` will be invoked only once for all classes that derive from `BaseClass<X>`. For example, if you have `ClassB : BaseClass<ClassA>` and `ClassA : BaseClass<ClassA>`, then the static constructor will be executed only once for these two types together.

Comment: added an update to explain better the problem and why the suggested answers can't apply

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a way to prevent `class X : Message<Y>` from being declared, but you can constrain use of `Message` subtypes to only those which you want.

```
R Foo<A>(A a) where A : Message<A>
{
  // …
}
```

If you use type reflection it will only be known at runtime whether your program is valid. Aim for solutions which can be checked by the compiler.

Comment: read the update in my post.
I put my checks in static constructor even because i have to run it at runtime (and its fine, it will rise exception if conditions are not met) but for performance reasons i can't run it in the instance constructor, the problem is that static constructor, afaik, doesn't expose the current class type and this is what i'm looking for alternative approaches

Comment: @FabioAngela I don't understand why the `[MyAttribute(MyMessages.Ping)]` attribute is relevant. What I am suggesting does not require static constructors or runtime checks. Maybe it does not suit your problem but I am now not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The base class's static constructor is called the first time the base class is accessed. This need not be a derived class instantiation, e.g. when a static method is called on the base class. The derived class simply has nothing to do with the base class's static constructor. Nor could it, since multiple classes can derive from the same generic base class.

Derived class instantiation is the earliest time at which the base class can know which derived class you're dealing with. You could test the object's run time type in a non-static base class constructor: `if (!typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(this.GetType())) throw new InvalidOperationException();`. The downside, of course, is that it's not caught at compile time.

Comment: read the update in my post. I can't run it in an instance method and btw static constructor, in generic classes, are called one time for every different T (and i'm already taking advantage of that in my desing)

Comment: The base class's static constructor is invoked for every `T` but not for every derived class. I.e. it's only executed once if multiple classes derive from the same `Base <T>`. There simply is no derived class available in the base class's static constructor, although you could use reflection to find them.